# Android - Can't hide VideoView after playback finishes

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-relativelayout

I have a VideoView within a RelativeLayout which is over the top of a WebView. All I want is to hide the video to reveal the WebView once the video finishes.

My problem is that I can initially hide the VideoView (parent Layout) in the onCreate, I can then show the video in onPrepared but once the video finishes I cannot hide it again.

If I don't hide the video initially and keep it open on screen then it hides when told to do so within onCompletion. It doesn't reshow the next time, like the first part is somehow blocking the second part.

The onCompletion and onPrepared are always called and other functions within these work just fine.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

private RelativeLayout videoLayout;
private VideoView videoHolder;

MediaPlayer vp = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    videoLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);
    videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    videoLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
}


public void videoPlayer() {
    if(videosCanPlay>0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delayVideo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        video = file_name;
        videoHolder.setVideoPath(video);

        videoHolder.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    } else {
        Log.i("PLAYLIST","Playlist Can't Play Yet");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        videoPlayer();
    }
}

public void hideVideo() {
    videoLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
}

public void showVideo() {
    videoLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer vp) {
    videoHolder.start();
    showVideo();
    duration = videoHolder.getDuration();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vp) {
    videoHolder.stopPlayback();
    hideVideo();
    videoPlayer();
}
```

Any help would be greatly received!

Comment: Why are calling video player() again after calling hide()?

Comment: I omitted a large chunk from the videoPlay() function that basically deals with the playlist, between video plays the WebView does it's thing for a designated time, hence the `Thread.sleep(delayVideo);` so once the video finishes it calls it again which gets the next video, waits for the web content to finish and then prepare the video player, this all works well, it's just hiding in-between all this that I can't figure out.

Comment: My be when you make Thread.sleep on the UI thread, it happens, that VideoLayout "receive command" to hide, but not actually hidden. After delay it's "receive command" to show, so, you can't see visibility change of View.

Comment: I mean, that Views don't hidden immediately. The change visibility on nearest onDraw() call from Android. But you blocks UI by calling Thread.sleep, so, when onDraw called, it's visibility already changed to VISIBLE

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I think. Is there a way to 'stack' the commands in order to wait for the UI change before sleeping?

Comment: Actually looks like there are some problems in design of app. But as quick solution you can try use some flag and `Handler.postDelayed()` method, to execute code with delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this. Sorry for formatting.

```
public void videoPlayer() {
    if(videosCanPlay>0) {
        video = file_name;
        videoHolder.setVideoPath(video);

        videoHolder.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    } else {
        Log.i("PLAYLIST","Playlist Can't Play Yet");
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                videoPlayer();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vp) {
    videoHolder.stopPlayback();
    hideVideo();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            videoPlayer();
        }
    }, delayVideo);
}
```